# Frequency components less than centre frequency of USRP

Tags: frequency, gnuradio, usrp

I have two USRP N210s connected together as a receiver and transmitter and I'm trying to send multi tone signals across the channel. However, I am finding extra frequency spikes mirrored about the centre frequency for when I send a signal with more than 2 tones.

I am using a low pass filter at the output with a cutoff frequency of 200kHz and the signal I am sending is constrained to 0-200kHz. I have an out of tree module that creates the multi tone signals that are evenly distributed within this bandwidth.

[image: 2 tone frequency components at the receiver]

As I increase the number of tones the reflected frequency components become more and more prominent to the point at which I can barely correlate the input and output signals.

[image]

This is what the transmitted multi tone signals looks like 
[image: Transmitted multi tone signal]

And here is the flowchart at the receiver end
[image: Receiver flowchart section]

The center frequency of the USRP source (receiver) is given by

```
uhd.tune_request(center_freq, rf_freq=(center_freq + lo_offset),rf_freq_policy=uhd.tune_request.POLICY_MANUAL)
```

which evaluates to 2.48GHz for which is the baseband frequency for the transmitting USRP

It may be something to do with the down conversion in the USRP or when GNURadio is actually sampling from the receiver with respect to this process.

Removing the LPF and connecting the FFT sink to the USRP source doesn't fix anything. The extra frequency spikes are still there (assuming the number of tones > 2)

Answer (score 1):

You're not specifying how you transmit your tones into the RX port of your USRP, but the most likely thing to have happened here is that you didn't use sufficient attenuation between TX and RX – and you're saturating the RX amplifier chain (hopefully not damaging it).

By saturating, you drive them into nonlinear operation, which would lead to a broadband intermodulation.